# Select que pega os últimos 30 dias a partir da data atual

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia pessoal, essa é uma parte da *query* que usei para buscar os últimos dias a partir da data atual. Funciona conforme esperado quando coloco *-20*, mas ao colocar *-30*, não.

```
WHERE viacao_os.creation_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() -30 AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Como posso consultar o que foi criado nos últimos 30 dias?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use o **[`DATE_ADD()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp)**:

```
WHERE viacao_os.creation_date
    BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Possivelmente sua consulta funciona com o *`-20`* por estarmos no dia *21*, ou seja, acaso.

Comment: WHERE viacao_os.creation_date
    BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE() INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
Order by viacao_os.os_id

Comment: Apresentou esse erro

Comment: @user107357, faltou uma vírgula no `date_add`. Corrigi, tenta novamente.

Comment: Apresentou esse erro  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
Order by viacao_os.os_id

Comment: OBRIGADO, Funcionou certinho, muito agradecido.

Comment: massa :) só lembra de marcar a resposta como aceita ;)

Answer (score -2):

Para mostrar os últimos 30 dias, use:

```
select 
    to_date(to_char(sysdate-30,'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') + rownum -1 AS data
from 
    all_objects
where 
    rownum <= to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy') - to_date(to_char(sysdate-30,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')+1;
```